# How to make ReadOnly ComboBox user control Tab Stoppable?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have created user control of three comboBoxes for choosing Date.I have set user control's ReadOnly property true, now the comboBox is not Tab stoppable even I set 'IsTabStop' property to 'true'.

Comment: Is this windows or web?

Comment: It's windows Desktop application.

Comment: Why ReadOnly & Tab Stop?

Comment: Can you show some code? How is the ReadOnly property implemented?

Comment: I makes it ReadOnly by setting 'IsHitTestVisible' property like 'cbday.IsHitTestVisible = !value'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest: ***TabIndex*** property, have you checked it's value (by default its *2147483647*)? You should apply that on each combobox in your user control.

Set the value of TabIndex according to when you want it to get the tab stop, for example if you have other elements on your window, setting the comboboxes index to 0, 1, and 2 will make them get focus on the first three tab presses.